# How query to get all child count Firebase use android studio

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I did not have the idea how query for all children in one time 
the image below show the structure of my database

How get count all child firebase in one query use android studio count lifts for all child

[image]

Comment: The only way to get the count of all those children is to load the entire `USA` node. Since that is horribly inefficient to get just a count of nodes, you'll likely instead want to keep a `count` property somewhere and update that whenever you add/delete child nodes.

Comment: Yeah, Frank's advice makes total sense. You will have to create a separate node for lift counts

Comment: - ok thats it i will make count property and update it on add data thank you so much Frank van Puffelen  and Yunus Kulyyev